# Заменить в строке друг за другом идущие <br> на один

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

есть

```
hello<br><br><br>world<br><br>kek<br><br>)0<br>
```

нужно

```
hello<br>world<br>kek<br>)0<br>
```

Comment: нужно писать код изначально нормальный, чтоб потом не писать костыли в виде регулярок убирающих кучу мусора

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может это обработка пользовательского ввода

Comment: @teran пользовательские br'ы ? и исключительно только они? какой-то узконаправленный пользовательский ввод.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский может выходные данные, после какого-нибудь js-текстового редактора

Comment: @teran так и зачем их убирать тогда? если пользователь вводил их намеренно, чтоб отделить текст? не кажется это бредом?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: @teran ну вот это и закольцовывается на мой первый комментарий))

Comment: Спасибо большое, MedvedevDev. Выручил)

Answer (score 3):

```js
const escape = 'hello<br><br><br>world<br><br>kek<br><br>)0<br>'.replace(/(<br>)+/g, '<br>');

console.log(escape);
```

Comment: Лучше типа такого: `(<\/?br>\s*)+`

Comment: на `$1` заменять лучше, а не `br`, несколько универсальнее

Comment: Пожалуйста, не давайте ответы на вопросы подобного типа. Не нужно потакать лентяям.

Comment: @Александр, реальность такова, что лучше помогать лентяям, чем садясь на их проект потом разбираться с их велосипедами xDD

Comment: @MedvedevDev то есть любите когда вы делаете, а зарплату получают они?)) ну а вообще лучше не сразу код писать, а всё же выяснить что надо в итоге. ибо может и думаете, что помогаете лентяям, чтоб в проекте не разбираться с их велосипедами, но на самом деле в таком вопросе и ответе скорее как раз вы сами помогаете строить этот самый велосипед облепленный костылями))